# Power BI compare row by itself (previous row)

Tags: mysql, sql-server, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am new to Dax in Power BI. I have a table that have columns:

`"elment_id", "version_Id", "type_name", "type_sorting", "workSet"`
AND `expected result` is the output result from the Dax query.

I am trying to compare `version_Id (x2, x2)` with `version_Id (x1, x1) (previous)`  if any change happened.

in another word, I am inserting to SQL database objects have always the same
`"elment_id", "type_name"` but the `"type_sorting", "workSet"` sometimes will be updated based on `"version_Id",`

| elment_id | version_Id | type_name | type_sorting | workSet | expected result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | x1 | Round Duct | 0 | w |  |
| 02 | x1 | Round Duct | 0 | m |  |
| 01 | x2 | Round Duct | 1 | y | True |
| 02 | x2 | Round Duct | 0 | m | False |

Comment: please provide sample data and expected output clearly in [How To](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277716/how-can-i-create-a-table-in-a-post)

Comment: I hope now is better!

Answer (score 0):

Try with measure, where you should manipulate FILTER part. First we check condition that must by equal (elementID/Type, and version = prev_version), then we add as many or  " || " to check if one of them is not equal :

```
Check =
VAR cc =
    MAX (
        CALCULATE (
            COUNTROWS ( changeCheck ),
            FILTER (
                ALL ( changeCheck ),
                (
                    SELECTEDVALUE ( changeCheck[elementID] ) = changeCheck[elementID]
                        && SELECTEDVALUE ( changeCheck[versionId] ) - 1 = changeCheck[versionId]
                        && SELECTEDVALUE ( changeCheck[Type] ) = changeCheck[Type]
                )
                    && (
                        IF (
                            ISBLANK ( SELECTEDVALUE ( changeCheck[Type_Sort] ) ),
                            "NullVal",
                            SELECTEDVALUE ( changeCheck[Type_Sort] )
                        )
                            <> IF ( ISBLANK ( changeCheck[Type_Sort] ), "NullVal", changeCheck[Type_Sort] )
                            || SELECTEDVALUE ( changeCheck[Workset] ) <> changeCheck[Workset]
                    )
            )
        ),
        0
    )
RETURN
    cc
```

[image]